# How do I access the array's element stored in my hash in Perl?

Tags: perl, hash, perl-data-structures

```
  # I have a hash 
  my %my_hash;

 # I have an array
  @my_array = ["aa" , "bbb"];

 # I store the array in my hash
  $my_hash{"Kunjan"} = @my_array;

 # But I can't print my array's element
  print $my_hash{"Kunjan"}[0];
```

I am new to Perl. Please help me.

Comment: Nobody's mentioned it yet, but check out the Data Structures Cookbook.  It has many examples for creating and accessing data in various nested structures.  You can read it on your machine by using the command `perldoc perldsc` and you can also find it at http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html

Comment: Also, see http://perlmonks.org/?node=references+quick+reference

Answer (score 14):

Your array syntax is incorrect.  You are creating an anonymous list reference, and `@my_array` is a single-element list containing that reference.

You can either work with the reference properly, as a scalar:

```
$my_array = ["aa" , "bbb"];
$my_hash{"Kunjan"} = $my_array;
```

Or you can work with the list as a list, creating the reference only when putting it into the hash:

```
@my_array = ("aa" , "bbb");
$my_hash{"Kunjan"} = \@my_array;
```

Answer (score 10):

If you had only put this at the top of your script:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```

...you would have gotten some error messages indicating what was wrong:

```
Global symbol "@my_array" requires explicit package name at kunjan-array.pl line 8.
Global symbol "@my_array" requires explicit package name at kunjan-array.pl line 11.
```

So, declare the array first with `my @my_array;` and then you would get:

```
Can't use string ("1") as an ARRAY ref while "strict refs" in use at kunjan-array.pl line 14.
```

- You created an arrayref and attempted to assign it to an array - see [perldoc perldata](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html) for how to declare an array
- You attempted to assign an array to a hash (you can only assign scalars, such as an arrayref - see [perldoc perlref](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html) for more about references)
- You need to dereference the hash element to get at the array element, e.g. `$my_hash{"Kunjan"}->[0]` - again see [perldoc perlref](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html) for how to dereference a hashref

Comment: @friedo: huh, I didn't think the `->` sugar worked before the first `->`. neat.

Answer (score 3):

You have a few errors in your program:

```
my @my_array = ("aa" , "bbb");
$my_hash{"Kunjan"} = \@my_array;
print $my_hash{"Kunjan"}[0];
```

I made three changes:

1. Added `my` in front of `@my_array` on the first line
2. Change the `[...]` to `(...)` on the first line
3. Add a `\` in front of @my_array on the second line

Comment: Might as well add that the backslash converts the array into an reference. Read about references here: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html

Answer (score 0):

Try these amendments:

```
my %my_hash;

# ["aa" , "bbb"] produces an array reference.  Use () instead
my @my_array = ("aa" , "bbb");

# 'Kunjan' hash is given reference to @my_array
$my_hash{ Kunjan } = \@my_array;

# bareword for hash key is nicer on the eye IMHO
print $my_hash{ Kunjan }[0];
```

However there is still one thing you need to consider if you use this method:

```
unshift @my_array, 'AA';
print $my_hash{ Kunjan }[0];    # => AA - probably not what u wanted!
```

So what you are probably after is:

```
$my_hash{ Kunjan } = ["aa" , "bbb"];
```

Then the hash is no longer referencing @my_array.

/I3az/

Answer (score 0):

Others already explained nicely what's what, but I would like to add, that (especially if you're new to Perl), it would be great if you spend some time and read the [perldsc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html) and [perllol](http://perldoc.perl.org/perllol.html) docs.